# Mysql IN behaves differently for strings, integers, and PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am updating an old PHP script to use PDO, and I am having trouble duplicating the original behavior.

The problem appears to be related to a neat little feature of the IN comparison that does not work with strings.

Given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `my_categories` (
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `categories` VARCHAR(255) NULL);

INSERT INTO my_categories (name, categories) VALUES
('Joe', '575'),
('Bob', '576'),
('Jim', '577'),
('Daisy','576,577'),
('Billy','576,597');
```

I can use this following SQL to match all the rows as required:

```
SELECT * as test FROM my_categories WHERE categories IN (575,576,577) 
 name   categories
 Joe    575
 Bob    576
 Jim    577
 Daisy  576,577
 Billy  576,597
```

However, with the slightest modification, Daisy and Billy are dropped from the results:

```
SELECT * as test FROM my_categories WHERE categories IN ('575','576','577')
 Joe    575
 Bob    576
 Jim    577
```

My problem is that I cannot duplicate the results in the first test at all using prepared statements in PDO.

Why is the behavior different, how can I get that functionality from a prepared statement, and is there a better way to compare "dumb" comma separated lists in a way to match all the given test cases?

Mysql Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/798faa/2

Comment: The better way is to not store it in a "dumb" comma-separated string in the first place.

Comment: `SELECT * as test FROM my_categories WHERE categories IN (575,576,577)` is comparing integers with a string; using loose casting.... basically, like comparing a string such as `"12 Monkeys"` with an integer `12` in PHP.... `576 = "576,577" in MySQL because `"576,577"` is cast to an integer as `576`

Comment: And you shouldn't be using "dumb" comma-separated lists in the first place.... if you absolutely have no other choice but to do so, then you should be using FIND_IN_SET()

Comment: basically: you have been exploiting something bad and PDO has ceased to allow you access to that exploit.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. So basically, things weren't even working before. That makes sense. There are certainly many rows that should have come up, but didn't. I found this bug by examining the difference in results so it just continued my impression that the original worked at all.

Comment: I now have an example using FIND_IN_SET that I can write up into an answer, summing up what you guys have rightly stated, but I'll leave it for a bit in case someone wants the 10 points. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/188c90/1